# Using the predict_proba() function of RandomForestClassifier in the safe and right way

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm using Scikit-learn. Sometimes I need to have the probabilities of labels/classes instead of the labels/classes themselves. Instead of having Spam/Not Spam as labels of emails, I wish to have only for example: 0.78 probability a given email is Spam.

For such purpose, I'm using `predict_proba()` with RandomForestClassifier as following:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, max_depth=None,
    min_samples_split=1, random_state=0)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y)
print(scores.mean())

classifier = clf.fit(X,y)
predictions = classifier.predict_proba(Xtest)
print(predictions)
```

And I got those results:

```
 [ 0.4  0.6]
 [ 0.1  0.9]
 [ 0.2  0.8]
 [ 0.7  0.3]
 [ 0.3  0.7]
 [ 0.3  0.7]
 [ 0.7  0.3]
 [ 0.4  0.6]
```

Where the second column is for class: Spam. However, I have two main issues with the results about which I am not confident. The first issue is that the results represent the probabilities of the labels without being affected by the size of my data? The second issue is that the results show only one digit which is not very specific in some cases where the 0.701 probability is very different from 0.708. Is there any way to get the next 5 digit for example?

Comment: I agree with Sebastien, look for a specific index in your prediction array, you'll probably have more precision. I wanted to precise that the result in predictions array are sorted by the name of the category, alphabetically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. I get more than one digit in my results, are you sure it is not due to your dataset ? (for example using a very small dataset would yield to simple decision trees and so to 'simple' probabilities). Otherwise it may only be the display that shows one digit, but try to print `predictions[0,0]`.
2. I am not sure to understand what you mean by "the probabilities aren't affected by the size of my data". If your concern is that you don't want to predict, eg, too many spams, what is usually done is to use a threshold `t` such that you predict 1 if `proba(label==1) > t`. This way you can use the threshold to balance your predictions, for example to limit the global probabilty of spams. And if you want to globally analyse your model, we usually compute the Area under the curve (AUC) of the Receiver operating characteristic (ROC) curve (see wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic)). Basically the ROC curve is a description of your predictions depending on the threshold `t`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am completing this answer regarding @Andreus 's one.

A random forest is indeed a collection of decision trees. However a single tree can also be used to predict a probability of belonging to a class. Quoting sklearn on the method `predict_proba` of the `DecisionTreeClassifier` class: `The predicted class probability is the fraction of samples of the same class in a leaf.`
And the prediction for a random forest is the average on all trees : `The predicted class probabilities of an input sample is computed as the mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest.`

Comment: Dear Sebastien, I hope that you're fine. Many thanks for your answers. They helped, sure. However, I think my English was not very clear. So, I'm sorry. Let me explain point number two in another way. If I provide 10 instances (new emails) to our produced model (Random Forest classifier). If the classifier gives me 0.6 as a probability that the email number 1 will be spam, is 0.6 affected by the other probabilities values of the other 9 instances, or the probability is independent and represents the probability of instance 1 to spam with 60% whatever the other 9 instances probabilities are.

Comment: And, regarding the first point and your suggestion to check the value of one prediction, actually I got the same number of digits. The only way to get more digits is to increase the number of estimators (trees) and such way for sure is not an acceptable way.

Comment: 1) About prediction precision:
I insist but this is not a question of number of trees. Even with a single decision tree you should be able to get probability predicitions with more than one digits. A decision tree aims at clustering the inputs based on some rules (the decision), and these _clusters_ are the leafs of the tree. If you have a leaf with 2 non-spam emails and one spam email from your training data, then the probability prediction for any email that belongs to this leaf/cluster (with regards to the rules established by fitting the model), is : 1/3 for spam and 2/3 for non-spam.

Comment: 2) About the dependencies in predictions:
Again Sklearn definition gives the answer : the probability is computed with regards to the leaf (corresponding to your email to test) 's characteristics : the number of instances of each class in this leaf. This is set when your model is fitted, so it only depends on the training data. In conclusion : the result is the probability of instance 1 to spam with 60% whatever the other 9 instances' probabilities are.

Comment: Great. I got point two. Really, many thanks to your time and trying explain it to me. Regarding the prediction precision, I will try to more explore my code, data, and the scikit-learn tree's parameters and structure to find out why I just got one digit. Thank you again, and have a nice day.

Comment: You're welcome ! Actually Sklearn has a nice explanation of Decision trees, and you can even plot you're decision tree (with the rules and everything) on simple dataset/problems to figure out what's happening. See [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree)

Answer (score 36):

A `RandomForestClassifier` is a collection of `DecisionTreeClassifier`'s. No matter how big your training set, a decision tree simply returns: a decision. One class has probability 1, the other classes have probability 0.

The RandomForest simply votes among the results. `predict_proba()` returns the number of votes for each class (each tree in the forest makes its own decision and chooses exactly one class), divided by the number of trees in the forest. Hence, your precision is exactly `1/n_estimators`. Want more "precision"? Add more estimators. If you want to see variation at the 5th digit, you will need `10**5 = 100,000` estimators, which is excessive. You normally don't want more than 100 estimators, and often not that many.

Comment: Dear Andreus, I hope that you're fine. Many thanks for your trying help in this question. If you don't mind, could you please check my explanation of my concern in my comment to Sebastien. Regarding your answer, yes, I tried to increase the number of trees and I got what you said. However, still with the size of 50 or 100 trees, I cannot see any more digits. Is your answer saying that if I got 0.7 that mean no more digits after seven and if we try to see digit behind seven we will get result like this: 0.70000? Sorry if I'm not understanding you.

Comment: What's the issue with more than 100 estimators? Is it too time-consuming?

Answer (score 5):

I am afraid the top-voted answer isn't correct (at least for the latest sklearn implementation).

According to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba), the probability of prediction is computed as the mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest. The class probability of a single tree is the fraction of samples of the same class in a leaf.

In other words, since Random Forest is a collection of decision trees, it predicts the probability of a new sample by averaging over its trees. A single tree calculates the probability by looking at the distribution of different classes within the leaf. Look at this image of a single decision tree to understand what it means to have different classes within the leaf. right leaf in 2nd child split has 75% yellow so prediction probability of class yellow will be 75%.
[image]

The scenario mentioned in the top-voted answer will only occur when every leaf of all trees have data points belonging to only one class in them.

References:

- https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html
- Image taken from https://www.displayr.com/how-is-splitting-decided-for-decision-trees/